# woocommerce product images have incorrect srcset paths in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Weird one here.

I have a Wordpress site with Woocommerce.

When I add products, and add a product image, I get a broken link in both admin and the live site. Both on the product list page and within the product.

The product image link itself is ok, the problem is the `srcset` attribute. The wrong path is set - it repeats the year and month ..

```
http://photographybyjean.eu/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/2017/01/city-photo-600x600.jpg 600w,
    ...
```

Removing the `srcset` attribute in Chrome Dev tools confirms that is the issue, because then the correct image is displayed.

Does anyone know where the Woocommerce php code for this is? I could easily fix it if I knew where it was generated from...

Oh, I am using the "ShopIsle" theme in case that matters.

EDIT: found the code - but it just calls `wp_get_attachment_image_srcset` :-( Surely the WP core can't be broken??? Any ideas?

Comment: I think it has something to do with the full size size of the original image ... smaller ones do not get a srcset, and so work.

Comment: still don't work on the product page itself...

Comment: Have the same issue. Is this resolved?

Comment: I am ashamed to say that I am sure I solved the issue but I can't recall how... super sorry... If I get time, I will go back and look at my site. Sorry again.

Answer (score 0):

We are on WordPress 4.9.5 and recently encountered the same issue.  Image SRC attribute is fine but SRCSET images have incorrect path.  As a result the image is not displayed and browsers show fail message about unloaded image.  Removing SRCSET attribute fixes the issue.  I suspect a WordPress bug for causing the issue.  My current solution is to use filters  to disable SRCSET from rendering and that fixed the problem.